# How to send mail through php mail on Amazon SES service?

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I want to send mail through php mail on Amazon SES service, In using PHP Mail But I am not able to send send. I already verify the my email_id. I am using this tutorial as reference http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786596/How-to-Use-Amazon-SES-to-Send-Email-from-PHP. **But It is not sending mail from Amazon SES services, please tell me where I am wrong ?**
Previously I was using the same id to send mails from localserver XAMPP. It was working.

**sendMail.php**

```
   <?php >
function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)
{
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';
    $from = "Senders_Email_Address";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(true); // SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // SMTP authentication
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->Host= "tls://email-smtp.us-east.amazonaws.com"; // Amazon SES
    $mail->Port = 465;  // SMTP Port
    $mail->Username = "Senders_Email_Address";  // SMTP  Username
    $mail->Password = "MyPassword";  // SMTP Password
    $mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,'Senders_Email_Address');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $to);
    if(!$mail->Send())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>    
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php
require 'sendMail.php';
$to = "Senders_Email_Address";
$subject = "Test Mail Subject";
$body = "Hi<br/>Test Mail<br/>Amazon SES"; // HTML  tags
Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**sendMail.php, class.phpmailer.php, class.smtp.php and index.php are in the same directory**.

Answer (score 6):

Neelabh, you are missing something. try following:

```
    <?php >
function Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body)
{
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$from = "verified_email address";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // SMTP authentication
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host= "tls://email-smtp.us-east.amazonaws.com"; // Amazon SES
$mail->Port = 465;  // SMTP Port
$mail->Username = "Your_SMTP_Username
";  // SMTP  Username
$mail->Password = "SMTP_Password";  // SMTP Password
$mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,'yourdomain.com or verified email address');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $to;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $to);

if(!$mail->Send())
return false;
else
return true;

}
?>
```

Also, create an index file like  below:

```
<?php
require 'Send_Mail.php';
$to = "to@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test Mail Subject";
$body = "Hi<br/>Test Mail<br/>Amazon SES"; // HTML  tags
Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
?>
```

Please note that if you have only sandbox access of SES, then the recipient email address  also needs to be verified. or you could verify your domain. let me know if this works.